# Why can't I get a Mongodb 2.6 text search score using the Ruby driver?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

mongoDB v 2.6.2

gem 'mongo', '~> 1.10.2'

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#return-the-text-search-score

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Tutorial

setup:

```
require 'mongo'
mongo_client = Mongo::MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
db = mongo_client.db("mydb")
coll = db.collection("testCollection")
```

This works:

```
coll.find({ "$text" => { "$search" => "one two three" } }).to_a
```

This return an error:

```
coll.find({ "$text" => { "$search" => "one two three" } }, { "score" => { "$meta" => "textScore" }}).to_a
```

RuntimeError: Unknown options [{"score"=>{"$meta"=>"textScore"}}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field selection for projection works a little differently with the ruby driver. You need to specify projection as a list of `:fields`:

```
require 'mongo'
include Mongo

client = MongoClient.new
db = client['test']
coll = db['text']

puts coll.find(
  { "$text" => { "$search" => "one two three" } },
  { :fields => [{ "score" => { "$meta" => "textScore" } }] }
).to_a
```

Comment: Many thanks, that sounds good. Unfortunately I can't check/accept your answer because now I'm getting `Mongo::OperationFailure: invalid operator: $search`. Im very sure my first example was working a couple of hours ago...

Comment: @ReillyBeacom That looks like you are not connecting to a MongoDB 2.6 instance, or at least anymore. Check the version you are connecting to as this syntax for `$search` with `$text` in `.find()` is only introduced from that version. Possibly you have managed to downgrade somewhere.

Comment: I had a server daemon on an old version hiding in the background and didn't realise I was connecting to it! Thanks for your answer; it was the nudge I needed in the right direction. Rolling along smoothly using the driver now.

Comment: On mongo 2.+, use `Mongo::Collection::View#projection` instead of the `fields` option.